# How do I fetch a row including foreign keys with DBAL?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, silex

Suppose I have two tables, `entry` and `language`. `entry` is mapped manytomany to `language` (every entry will have a language). And language has two columns, `code` ('en') and `name` ('English').

In Symfony (working code), I used this code in the controller:

```
$entries = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Entry')->findAll();
```

and it gets all the entry's with their language information as well. And in Twig I can use `entry.language.name` (after `{$ for entry in entries %}`).

I am now using Silex (code doesn't work). Here is my code in the controller:

```
$entries = $app['db']->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM entry');
```

but Twig can't use `entry.language.name`, but only `entry.language_code`. It's like the `language` data isn't in the `$entries` object.

Is there a way in Silex to pass `$entries` to Twig so that I can use `entry.language.name`?

Comment: I can sort of accomplish the same goal with joins, but it adds a lot of extra work that I would like to avoid.

Comment: Do you use Doctrine in Silex? In Symfony it was probably lazy loaded.

Comment: I do, DoctrineServiceProvider.

Comment: `DoctrineServiceProvider` is only Doctrine DBAL integration. In Symfony you used Doctrine ORM. It's ORM that does the whole "magic" like lazy loading, hydrating to entities etc..

Comment: @dragoste So I suppose that means I will have to do the joins? Just curious, will the joins (entry.language_name) execute faster than entry.language.name (assuming I don't join all of the columns)?

Comment: It means that you're doing simple SQL queries and you get simple flat arrays of what you've queried. That's all.

Comment: Do you use the ORM with entities in your silex application? Or just the connection? If you use `DoctrineOrmServiceProvider` you will be able to do the same as Symfony.

Comment: I do not use ORM in Silex. It seems the answer is that I can not do it without Doctrine ORM.